# CSS bottom: 0; position: absolute; parent position: relative; not working

Tags: css, css-position

At [this page](http://test.insightcomdes.com.au/) I have the navigation menu `.slider-btm` underneath the head image ("Branding, Print, Websites & Movies, Displays & Signage")  with:

```
.slider-btm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

and parent:

```
<div class="slider-outer-wrapper" style="position:relative">
```

yet the navigation menu `.slider-btm` is not at the bottom of the screen. I see the following:

[image]

I wish to have this menu at the bottom like the menu at the bottom of [brand.insightdesign.com.au](http://brand.insightdesign.com.au)

Help appreciated.

Comment: `is not at the bottom of the screen` -->this is position fixed

Comment: `bottom:0` to .slider-btm class is working with absolute positioning but the `max-height: 1000px` to .slider-outer-wrapper is restricting the height of the parent div to 1000px from 100vh. Just remove the max-height property from .slider-outer-wrapper class. brand.insightdesign.com.au used the same technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ultra-basic way, that website (that you have removed from your question) would have the container measure the height of your window and attach the height of the window to the header(container) and then absolute position the menu to the bottom of this container (see code for a very rough example)

```css
.container {
background:red;
position:relative;
height:100vh;
}
li {
list-style:none;
float:left;
}
.menu {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<h1>This is more content</h1>
```

If you need anything further explaining, let me know.

### --- UPDATE ---

Instead of using JavaScript to work out the height of your browser window, simply add `height:100vh` to the container height. This will match the container height to the browser height, give you the same outcome (just through CSS rather than JavaScript - with the added positive of that this you won't have to assign this to an on resize in case the user resizes their screen). I have updated the code above.

### --- FURTHER UPDATE ---

Thanks, by moving `.slider-btm` out of `.slider-outer-wrapper` container, this should resolve your issue so that `.slider-btm` can sit at the bottom of your container which is 100vh.

Comment: Does `brand.insightdesign.com.au` do something like the above?

Comment: What website have I removed from my question? :-)

Comment: Sorry, You moved it, i didn't see it at the bottom of the question now. Instead of using javascript to measure the window height, you can use height: 100vh within the container so that your container would match the height of your window. Then after this container, you can carry on with other content. This will give you the effect your menu is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: `#pgc-80-0-0 {height: 100vh;}` does not change anything. .slider-outer-wrapper is already `height: 100vh` but that doesn't seem to be active.

Comment: move .slider-btm out of #pg-80-0 so it's the next element and that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, moving `.slider-btm` out of `<div class="slider-outer-wrapper" style="position:relative">` resolved the issue. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That's great news. Glad it's now working. I've updated the answer so if you can upvote and accept, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the bar fixed at the bottom of the screen, also while scrolling?

Use `position: fixed`

```
.slider-btm {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: No, not fixed at the bottom of the screen, but like the menu at the bottom of brand.insightdesign.com.au

Comment: Well, it IS exactly like this atm...
What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I see to my question (after clearing my browser cache and cookies). Do you see something different?

Comment: I don't see it like you do. For me it looks like your desired result. 
Which browser are you using and on which resolution does it occur?

Comment: I am using Chrome on a 5K Mac. I will check at home on a 2K screen.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but do you use the browser zoom? Try CMD "+" or CMD "-" in the browser to check if you are on 100% view size. Chrome iself works fine, on a mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is the the different screen resolution of the devices , add this line to the "slider-outer-wrapper" class

```
.slider-outer-wrapper{
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
}
```

you have added max-height property , please remove it

[image]

after removing

[image]

Comment: Hi subbu. Position is already `relative` and height is already `100vh` so adding the CSS above makes no change. :)

Comment: hi steve, just had a look at the code , i suppose the max-height property is causing issue